# Install and register game to local steam client programmatically

Tags: steam, testing, deployment, automation

I'm doing some automated UI testing - I want to programmatically install a game and then launch it.

From what I've seen, the Steam client isn't very accessible for UI automation (I can't view elements in [Accessibility Insights](https://accessibilityinsights.io/) so I can't automate element interaction).

I'm able to download the games to a folder using [SteamCMD](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD):

```
force_install_dir <where you want to download the game files>
app_update <game's appid> validate
```

This puts the games in the directory I have specified, but I haven't found a way to programmatically register the games with the locally installed Steam client.

As a last resort, I can use this command to launch the application installer:

```
start steam://install/719950
```

And then use hardcoded coordinates to click the "Next >" button, however I would really like to avoid this.